# Intentionally drop state when using suppress for rate limiting updates to KTable

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka Streams 2.3.1 suppress() operator to limit the number of updates being sent to the underlying KTable.

The use case here is that in my processing logic, I want to make an HTTP call, however to limit the number of calls, I am windowing the stream and aggregating source topic messages that fall into the same time window to make a single API call.

Code looks roughly as follows

```
KTable<Windowed<String>, List<Event>> windowedEventKTable = inputKStream
    .groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
    .aggregate(Aggregator::new, ((key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate.aggregate(value)), stateStore)
    .suppress(Suppressed.untilTimeLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(5), maxRecords(500).emitEarlyWhenFull())
    .mapValues((windowedKey, groupedTriggerAggregator) -> {//code here returning a list})
    .toStream((k,v) -> k.key())
    .flatMapValues((readOnlyKey, value) -> value);
```

The problem I am running into is that while the windows exceeding the record limit are emitted, the state is preserved. At some point the state for a single time window grows into multiple MB's, causing the supress store changelog message to exceed the topic's `max.message.bytes` limit. For our use case, as soon as window is emitted we actually don't care about leftover state and it would be safe to drop it.

As we are sharing the Kafka Cluster between multiple teams, the team running the cluster is hesitant to increase cluster level `max.message.bytes` property beyond 10 MB's that we require.

Do I have any options other than implementing my logic using `transformValues`? If not, are there any future Kafka Streams enhancements that would be able to handle this more out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

> For our use case, as soon as window is emitted we actually don't care about leftover state and it would be safe to drop it.

For this case, you can set the store retention time (default is 1 day) to the same value as the specified grace period, via `aggregation()` parameter `Materialized.withRetentiontTime(...)`.

> The problem I am running into is that while the windows exceeding the record limit are emitted, the state is preserved. At some point the state for a single time window grows into multiple MB's, causing the supress store changelog message to exceed the topic's max.message.bytes limit.

This is actually an interesting statement, and looking at your code, I just want to clarify something: As you limit by time and allow to emit early based on cache size, it seems that you have a lot of records that are out of order and update the state further even after an intermediate result was emitted. If you purge the state via retention time as describe above you need to consider the following:

- Purging state won't affect any emits that are triggered base on cache size, because, the state will only be purges after the retention time passed.
  0 Furthermore, purging state implies that all out of order records the appear after purging would **not** be processed at all, but would be dropped (because retention time implicitly marks input records with smaller timestamp as "late").

However, overall it seems that you don't really care about out of order data and event-time windows as it's ok for you to "arbitrarily" put records into a window as the only goal is to reduce the number of external API calls. Hence, it seems appropriate that you actually switch to processing time semantics by using `WallclockTimetampExtractor` (instead of the default extractor). For ensure that each record is only emitted once, you should change the `suppress()` configuration to only emit "final" results.